# JavaScript Volume Up and Down Buttons

Tags: javascript

So I have volume up and down buttons that displays a notification every time the volume is increased.

Volume Up

```
  function volumeUp() {
    if (currentVolume < .9) {
      currentVolume += .1;
      sound.volume = currentVolume;
      var $toastContent = $('<span>Volume '+ parseInt(currentVolume * 100)+ ' %' + '</span>' );
      Materialize.toast($toastContent, 2000);
    } else {
      alert("Max Vol")
    }
  }
```

Volume Down

```
  function volumeDown() {
    if (currentVolume > .1) {
      currentVolume -= .1;
      sound.volume = currentVolume;
      var $toastContent = $('<span>Volume '+ parseInt(currentVolume * 100)+ ' %' + '</span>' );
      Materialize.toast($toastContent, 2000);
    } else {
      alert("Min Vol")
    }
  }
```

The problem I'm having is, when I get to < 80% it starts to alert as 89 then 99 instead of 90 and 100.

Also when I get to 10% and I decrease it, it shows as 2% not 0%.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: And as a side note, learn how to use a debugger

Comment: I've been messing with the debugger for ages. That's why I posted here. Thanks for the link. Will try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Amit mentioned it's about floating point math.
If you open the console and declare a variable and initialize it with `0.7 + 0.1` you'll see that it's actual value will be 0.7999999999999999

For your media player it won't make a difference so it's only about displaying this value. You have two options:

1) Work with integers:

```
function volumeUp() {
  if (currentVolume < 90) {
    currentVolume = currentVolume + 10;
    sound.volume = currentVolume / 100;
    var $toastContent = $('<span>Volume '+ currentVolume+ ' %' + '</span>' );
    Materialize.toast($toastContent, 2000);
  } else {
    alert("Max Vol")
  }
}
```

2) Apply rounding after each addition:

```
currentVolume = Math.round((currentVolume + 0.1) * 10) / 10;
```

or

```
currentVolume = (parseFloat(currentVolume) + 0.1).toFixed(1); //string representation with one decimal
```

Comment: Wonderful! Used the first solution. Thank you B0Andrew

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the below line does not makes sense.

```
currentVolume = currentVolume += .1;
```

Either do `currentVolume = currentVolume + .1;` or `currentVolume += .1;`

After `.9` and below `.1` if you want to make an increment or decremenet of `1` instead of `10` then you should do

```
currentVolume += .01; // Instead of .1 in your volumeUp() function
```

and

```
currentVolume -= .01; // Instead of .1 in your volumeDown() function
```